# Custom checkstyle to make sure each comment ends in a period

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am attempting to create a custom CheckStyle in IntelliJ IDEA(with Maven)that will enforce the following rule:
a period after every single comment

I've looked at this post [Custom Checkstyle Check Nesting Isssue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067415/custom-checkstyle-check-nesting-isssue), and seen that whitespace does not count as a token. I am not sure how to parse the comments and check for the period.

I am extending the puppycrawl Checkstyle tools and using the visitToken method for the implementation. In the checkstyle.xml I am adding my check into the TreeWalker module of the Checker module.

Does anyone have any theories on how to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to examine the existing checkers (just like in the linked post), it is very likely that you can find one which is quite close to the expected behaviour.

E.g. [TrailingComment](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/misc/trailingcomment.html) check in your case.

With this configuration (snippet):

```
...
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="TrailingComment">
            <property name="format" value="^---dummy-pattern---should-not-match-any-line---$"/>
            <property name="legalComment" value="\.$"/>
            <message key="trailing.comments" value="Comment should end with dot."/>
        </module>
    </module>
...
```

For the following Java code:

```java
class C
{
    int i;  // OK.
    int j;  // error
// OK.
// error
}
```

This report will be produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkstyle version="10.3.4-SNAPSHOT">
  <file name="...">
    <error line="4" column="13" severity="warning" message="Comment should end with dot." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.TrailingCommentCheck"/>
    <error line="6" column="13" severity="warning" message="Comment should end with dot." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.TrailingCommentCheck"/>
  </file>
</checkstyle>
```

Or - if this is not exactly what you need - you can create a new checker based on the [TrailingCommentCheck](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/TrailingCommentCheck.java) class.